# UWP NavigationView is not supported

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to make UWP application with sidemenu. When I try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) tutorial, I get an error in XAML:

```
NavigationView is not supported in a windows universal project
```

Build options:

```
Target Version:   Win 10 Creators Update (10.0; Build 15063)
Minimum Version:  November Update (10.0' Build 10586)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Requirements to use NavigationView Class:

> Device family: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (introduced **v10.0.16299.0**)
>
> API contract: Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (introduced **v5**)

Reference: [NavigationView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview)

Comment: Do i need some kind of special download ? Because when I go for windows update, I have everything up to date

Comment: You will get upgrade.... but it is happening in waves.. so may take some time... Look into below article and see if it can help you in obtaining immediately.... https://www.pcworld.com/article/3234186/windows/download-windows-10-fall-creators-update.html

Answer (score 3):

`NavigationView` has also been backported to support all versions of Windows 10 starting with 14393 (Anniversary Update).

You can add it via NuGet and file issues here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the target version to `Win 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)`. Also the `NavigationView` control will not work on any previous version of Windows so your app will crash everywhere except 16299 and above if you use the `NavigationView` control without any API version checks.

And to upgrade your PC to FCU you can use the tool provided [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Answer (score 1):

You can use OneCode.Windows.UWP.Controls.NavigationView, it works on all Win10 Versions.
You can get it from nuget 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/OneCode.Windows.UWP.Controls.NavigationView/

Comment: How does one Implement this @Fruit? 
Can you share a sample code?

Comment: Never mind. I restarted Visual studio and am now able to see it in the namespace.